# ServiceStack might create several sessions instead of one on concurrent requests from one browser

Tags: servicestack

ServiceStack supports Sessions https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions.

Does ServiceStack use some other mechanism except cookies to identify client (browser) reliably?

Let's assume the following scenario:
I open a browser with several tabs (saved previously) and the browser does not have any session related cookies (ss-pid, etc) yet. 
All tabs *simultaneously* go to the server and the server (ServiceStack) might create several sessions instead of one.

The scenario might look artificial, but I wonder if ServiceStack "fixes" the scenario with *concurrent* requests from not-yet-identified browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `ss-id` and `ss-pid` Cookies are what contains the **session identifier** to locate the users Session, which is essentially just an instance of [IAuthSession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs) persisted in the registered `ICacheClient` at a location containing the Session Id. Without the session ids (contained in the Cookies), there is no way for ServiceStack to match/locate or correlate anonymous requests to the same users session.

But Cookies are sticky by nature, i.e. when you open multiple tabs, browsers automatically re-send the same cookies that were registered for that domain.

If multiple anonymous (i.e. no Cookies set) tabs are open and one of them makes a request, ServiceStack will detect no cookies were sent and automatically generate and instruct the client to add new `ss-id`, `ss-pid` cookies. From that point any future HTTP requests (inc. Ajax Requests) from any of the existing tabs will contain the same cookies. So when one of the tabs authenticates, all future requests from any of the tabs will be sending requests within the same authenticated session.

#### Can use HTTP Headers for Session Requests

From **v4.0.32+** the Session Ids can also be sent using the HTTP Headers, e.g: `X-ss-id`, `X-ss-pid`.

Comment: sounds good, but what if several tabs authenticates at the same time? Several ids would be issued (sessions) but later only one would be used and other ones become phantoms. right?

Comment: @AC. as soon as one of the browser gets a HTTP Response back, cookies are added to future requests from all browsers. If multiple simultaneous requests are made without cookies (i.e. at exactly the same time), It's up to the browsers if cookies from first response wins or last wins.